# Difference between *str[] and str[][]

Tags: c++

I dont understand the use of  *str[]  in this code,is it diff from str[][] used in this code?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[10], b[10], c, buffer[50], str[1][9], s[10];
    //decalaring char a, b, buffer, str[][], s//
    int y;

    ofstream out;
    out.open("output.cpp");
    out<<("\nOPCODE\tMACHINE_CODE\n");
    do
    {
        y = 0;
        cout<<"ENTER THE OPCODE&MACHINE CODE";
        cin>>a>>b;
        out<<"\n"<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\t"<<"\n";
        cout<<"PRESS 1 TO CONTINUE";
        cin>>y;
    }while(y == 1);
    out.close();
    ifstream in;
    in.open("output.cpp");
    while(in)
    {
        c = in.get();
        cout<<c;
    }
    in.close();
    cout<<"ENTER THE OPCODE TO SEARCH";
    cin>>s;
    in.open("output.cpp");
    in.getline(buffer,50);
    while(in)
    {
        *str[0] = '\0'; // i dont understand the use of *str[] here, is it diff from str[][]?
        *str[1] = '\0';
        in>>str[0];
        in>>str[1];
        if(strcmpi(str[0], s) == 0)
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<str[0]<<"\t"<<str[1];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same as your question. [I have big confusion to understand the difference between `char *var[3]`, `char var[3][15]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979312/i-have-big-confusion-to-understand-the-difference-between-char-var3-char)

Comment: `iostream.h`? Why? We are not in 1990 any more.

Comment: @LionKing: No, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

`*x` means "dereference the pointer `x`". Now, whenever you have an array in a position where the language expects a pointer it implicitly decays to a pointer to the first element.

So

```
*str[0]='\0';
```

means "assign `'\0'` to the first element of the 1-element character array `str[0]`, which is itself the first element of the 9-element array `str`".

It means exactly the same as

```
str[0][0] = '\0';
```

and arguably should have been written that way. Or `str` should have been declared as `char str[9]` in the first place.

Comment: thanks you so much for replying, but i need to understand these points-1)what is the advantage of using *str[0] ,2) is there any simple way you can suggest ,3) *str[1]='\0' means str[1][0]='\0'.